# Fabric for Android/Eclipse - Unable to Login

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

OK, so I'm trying to get [Fabric](https://fabric.io) up and running for my Android project using Eclipse as my IDE..

Has anyone done this successfully?

Using "Install New Software..." and putting in `https://fabric.io/downloads/eclipse` I get version `2.1.0` installed. I then restart Eclipse, as asked.

When Eclipse boots, the little Fabric toolbar icon is indeed there, but when I click it and attempt to login, none of the text that I type goes into the fields. It instead acts as if I'm focused on whatever window I previously had clicked, for instance if I type `S` it moves to the first project in my workspace that starts with `S`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Seems odd, but if you copy and paste in your username and password does that work?

Comment: It doesn't. It's as if the email/password fields don't have keyboard focus, despite clicking on them and the cursor blinking in the clicked on box.

Comment: Pinged you an email as well, but your logs would be great to have to get to the bottom of this!

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that changing Java to 1.7 solves the issue.

Comment: Aha! Success! I was in touch with the Fabric folks (who were very nice for the record), but I didn't feel comfortable sending them the log files they asked for as they contained sensitive information about project names in my workspace and whatnot.

Regardless, I switched to JDK 1.7 and it works perfectly now. Thanks ConJoBa!